# Пустые массивы c#

Tags: c#, консоль, методы

У меня есть массив в классе setArray и там же метод.
В этом методе я задаю значение массиву.
Но когда я в другом классе и методе пытаюсь вывести массив он пустой.
Как решить?

Код:

```cs
class setArray
{

public string[] array = new string[20];

public void SetArrayMethod()
{
    array[1] = "Array 1";
}

}
```

Другой файл:

```cs
class GetArray
{

public void GetArrayMethod()
{
    setArray arrayClass = new setArray();

    Console.Write(arrayClass.array[1]);
}

}
```

Comment: Изменил. Добавил код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы присвоить значение массиву нужно присваивать значение в конструкторе
Вот так. Тогда код сработает который ниже у вас.

```C#
class setArray
{

public string[] array = new string[20];

public setArray()
{
    array[1] = "Array 1";
}

}
```

Либо нужно вызвать метод `SetArrayMethod()` у объекта `arrayClass` вот так

```C#
class GetArray
{

public void GetArrayMethod()
{
    setArray arrayClass = new setArray();
    arrayClass.SetArrayMethod();
    Console.Write(arrayClass.array[1]);
}

}
```

Так тоже сработает, выбирайте что вам удобнее. 
Вы просто немножко не поняли логику работы.
Вы создали класс `setArray` В нем у вас есть поле public `string[] array = new string[20];` оно все еще пустое. При создании объекта создается и пустое поле и что бы его заполнить нужно вызвать метод `SetArrayMethod()`.